# Laravel 5.4 Mutator not working

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, eloquent, mutators

I have a mutator which is not working, I've looked through here, tried some suggestions and yet nothing appears to get it working.

Here is my Model:

```
...

protected $fillable = [
    'energy_types'
];

...

public function getEnergyTypesAttribute($value)
{
    $types = explode(',', $value);
    $fuels = array();
    foreach($types as $type){
        switch ($type){
            case '2':
                $fuelType = 'Gas (Reticulated)';
                break;
            case '3':
                $fuelType = 'Gas (Bottled)';
                break;
            default:
                $fuelType = 'Electricity';
        }
        $fuels[] = array(   "id" => $type,
                            "name" => $fuelType);
    }

    return $fuels;
}
```

Stored in the database as so:

**energy_types**

1

1,2

1

Controller:

```
if($participant->isRetailer){
       $retail = Retailer::find($participant->id);
       $participant->energyTypes = $retail->energy_types;
```

If I do a dump here of *$retail*, *energy_types* is still just like so:

```
["energy_types"]=>
    string(3) "1,2"
```

I've tried changing how I get *$retail*, re-migrated, tried even setting an attribute (doesn't work also).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `If I do a dump here` - what are you dumping? The `$retail` model? Is `energy_types` an attribute in your database, or a getter for a non-attribute?

Comment: e.g. if I do var_dump($retail). energy_types is a column in the database. I want each time it comes out to convert the values into the array you see above.

Comment: Can you try changing your accessor to simply return `return 'test';` and see whether it's even getting called? Dump `$retail` and access `$retail->energy_types`

Comment: @fubar that seems to be working and I've just tried $retail->energy_types and it is returning what i want.
Really not sure what has gone here and why it is magically working

Comment: Does your method work now too, or just `return 'test'`? And does dumping the value work, or only accessing it directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Mutator functions are like "setEnergyTypesAttribute".

Your code snippets, however, is showing that you're trying to define an Accessor.

Anyway, if you are trying to add a custom attribute to a Model when retrieving data from database, here is how you do it.

```
...
protected $appends = ['foo'];
...
public function getFooAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['bar'] . ' foo'; 
}
```

where "bar" is an original attribute in the Model.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Sem, actually solved this a long time ago, but good to put an answer in, thanks :)